# I need a case statement to get at prior month and prior year of prior month. Is it possible to use subdate(current_date())

Tags: sql, domo

```
CASE    
    WHEN SUBDATE(`invoice date`,DAYOFMONTH(`invoice date`)) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE()),DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    THEN 'Prior Month'
    WHEN SUBDATE(`invoice date`,DAYOFYEAR(`invoice date`)) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE()),DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    THEN 'Prior Year'
    ELSE 'Out of Scope'
END
```

Comment: That's a case _expression_.

Comment: Which dbms? Domo?!?

Comment: This worked...CASE
 WHEN MONTH(`invoice date`) = MONTH(CURDATE())-1
     AND YEAR(`invoice date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    THEN 'Prior Month'
 WHEN MONTH(`invoice date`) = MONTH(CURDATE())-1
     AND YEAR(`invoice date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1
    THEN 'Prior Year'
 ELSE 'out of scope'
END

Comment: When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. That's why the dbms used is extra important information. MONTH() and YEAR() functions are not standard, but still supported by a bunch of databases.

Comment: Thanks jarlh, yes its DOMO.  I did find a code that worked and showed above.

Comment: Remember that MySQL instance of DOMO runs version 5.6; additionally you may want to try RedShift DataFlows (ask to your CSM).